# Cannot get nested modules to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make some common scopes for models to be sharing, so i created this:

```
lib
|_ scopes
   |_ scope.rb
   |_ bars.rb
```

---

```
# lib/scopes/scope.rb
module Scope
end
```

---

```
# lib/scopes/bars.rb
module Scope
  module Bars
    def self.included(base)
      base.class_eval{
        scope :somescope, lambda{ where(:foo => :bar) }
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Now when i put this in a model:

```
include Scope::Bars
```

It throws an error: **Expected c:/sites/app_name/lib/scopes/bars.rb to define Bars**

For some bizarre reason, This doesn't happen when i just use the rails console to test instead of WEBrick server.

Also it perfectly works if i don't use sub-models, Like: `include Bars` would work just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Scopes` module? Btw, there's no need to create a separate file for defining the module itself.

Comment: @KL-7 Hmm, I don't know why but that actually worked! Thanks! Is there a reason why it needs it pluralized?

Comment: Rails auto-loading mechanism relies on the file paths to locale classes and modules definitions. You had `Scope::Bars` defined in `scopes/bars.rb` (note `s` in `scopes` directory name). Hence the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following structure

```
lib
|_ scopes
   |_ scope.rb
   |_ bars.rb
```

expects you to define the top module as `Scopes`, not `Scope`. Either rename the folder from `scopes` to `scope` or change your module to

```
# lib/scopes/bars.rb
module Scopes
  module Bars
    def self.included(base)
      base.class_eval do
        scope :somescope, lambda { where(:foo => :bar) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```